# What is the default search path for find_package in windows using cmake?

Tags: cmake

I am porting some code over to windows and my cmake checks for the package Libavahi using

```
find_package(Libavahi)
```

I have the headers, dll, etc. but I'm not sure where to place these such that cmake will find them.

Where can I put these files to be found by cmake?  They're in a folder called `usr`.

I see that the module path is specified using:

```
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/Modules/")
```

but I'm wondering if there is a default location that will be searched as well

Comment: You may want to check answer to ["find libavahi with cmake"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18630794/2419207), which contains links to relevant parts of cmake documentation.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The [CMake manual](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html) fully specifies the rather complicated search order for the different `find_*` commands. Unfortunately, since Windows lacks a default directory structure à la `/usr/local/lib`, it is hard to come up with reasonable defaults here.

One of the most reliable ways of managing directories is through environment variable hints. You simply add an `$ENV{MY_VAR}` to the `HINTS` section of the find command and then document that environment variable in your project's readme. Most users that are capable of compiling a C++ program know how to use environment variables, and it is way more convenient than having to give the path on the command line every time (although it never hurts to leave that as an additional option).

For `find_package` CMake offers a special mechanism on Windows called the [package registry](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-packages.7.html#package-registry). CMake maintains a list of package information in the Windows registry under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Kitware\CMake\Packages\`. Packages build from source can register there using the [`export`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/export.html) command. Other projects build later on the same machine will then be able to find that package without additional configuration. This is quite powerful if you need to build a lot of interdependent projects from source on the same machine.

Update: Starting with version 3.12, CMake now [implicitly considers the `<PackageName>_Root` environment variable a `HINT`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.12/policy/CMP0074.html) for every `find_package` call.

Comment: +1 for the $ENV{VAR} tip. It is exactly what I use in my projects and works very well (even on Unix).

Comment: I've specified the files' directory with the HINTS param.  On Linux the NAMES param for libavahi was `libavahi-client.so`.  I tried `libavahi-client.dll.a`, located (using HINTS) in `C:/Documents\ and\ Settings/IEUser/My\ Documents/Downloads/avahi-client/usr/lib/` but still no luck.  Any recommendation?

Comment: export approach is better that that global C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake\share\cmake-3.3\Modules directory!

Comment: In case anyone is a cmake syntax tard like me... Here is an example line(Mind that OpenCV is my package, and I have created OPENCV_DIR in environment variables and it points to the open cv build directory on my system (from source)) : 
find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED HINTS $ENV{OPENCV_DIR})

Answer (score 3):

In the newer versions of cmake, you can use the `--debug-find` option to list the directories that cmake is searching through.  Somethin like:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DBUILD_TOOLS=ON --debug-find .
```